# expand the whole div along with the sub menu items when hover on the menu list

Tags: html, css

i have kept my menu bar in the div...when i scroll on the menu items the list appears..but i want the whole div to move expand along with the sub menus list....please can any one help...
this is my complete code..

```
*<doctype! html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
    nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;

    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;background:blue;">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>*
```

Comment: What do you mean you want the div to expand with the sub menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make sure the length of the sub-menu is the same as the main menu label by forcing a fixed width on the main menu label like so:

```
nav ul li { width: 170px; }
```

I have created a [live snippet here](http://jsbin.com/ureyiy/1/edit). However, note that doing this will cause the longer labels to be tucked to the second line.